# Solidity - function "now" result

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, blockchain, geth-debugging

I would like yo know what kind of format is returned by the function `now`.

I am calling this function in a contract and sending the result like an event to my .js file. The structure that I see is like this:

[image: output "now" function]

I would like to compare this time with the obtained with `new Date().getTime();` in javascript, but I dont know the meaning of "c,e,s" and I am not sure if it is the same kind of format (the length of the result number is different) or I should manage it first. I that case, how could I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using web3.js. The type for numeric values returned from a contract is `BN` or `BigNumber`, depending on the web3.js version.

In both cases, `.toString()` will give you a string representation of the number, and `.toNumber()` will give you a number, but be careful about precision! JavaScript can't safely handle numbers larger than 2<sup>53</sup>-1.

For a timestamp, you should be fine just using `.toNumber()`.

Comment: For `now` it is probably the same, but generally speaking, `toFixed` gives "better results" than `toString` (better in the fact that you always get a string in clear format).

Comment: When I apply `toNumber()` I obtain `1535277654` (the "c" argument in the image), but when I apply `new Date().getTime()` the result is `1535277681189`. They have different size, so I cannot manage them correctly. What is the difference? Is there any way to obtain the same length? @smarx

Comment: The block timestamp is in seconds since the Unix epoch. JavaScript's timestamps are in _milliseconds_ since the Unix epoch. Just divide the JavaScript timestamp by 1,000. E.g. `Math.floor(new Date() / 1000)`.